# How to use wordpress editor

Tags: wordpress

```
 - wp_register_script( 'tinymce-min-js',
   "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.1/tinymce.min.js"); 
       wp_enqueue_script( 'tinymce-min-js' );

    <textarea name="message"></textarea>

     tinymce.init({ 
                toolbar1: "code | preview | fullscreen | emotEventns | blockquote | cut copy paste | undo redo removeformat | save",
                toolbar2: "table | image | link | charmap | hr | media | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent",
                toolbar3: "fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | subscript superscript",
                plugins: "code advlist fullscreen media preview table image link textcolor charmap emotEventns",
                menubar: false, 
                width: 800,
                height: 470,
                resize: false,
                fullpage: false,    
                selector: "textarea"
            });
```

I have tried this but I am not getting editor .I want use editor for text area. Please try to solve this. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: in frontend or backend?

Comment: In both side it is not working

Comment: I don't really understand what are you trying to do there, but WP has function to call the editor: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            tinymce.init({ 
                toolbar1: "code | preview | fullscreen | emotEventns | blockquote | cut copy paste | undo redo removeformat | save",
                toolbar2: "table | image | link | charmap | hr | media | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent",
                toolbar3: "fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | subscript superscript",
                //plugins: "code advlist fullscreen media preview table image link textcolor charmap emotEventns",
                menubar: false, 
                width: 800,
                height: 470,
                resize: false,
                fullpage: false,    
                selector: "textarea"
            });
    });

</script>
```

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    tinymce.init({ 
     toolbar1: "code | preview | fullscreen | emotEventns | blockquote | cut copy paste | undo redo removeformat | save",
     toolbar2: "table | image | link | charmap | hr | media | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent",
     toolbar3: "fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic underline strikethrough | subscript superscript",
     //plugins: "code advlist fullscreen media preview table image link textcolor charmap emotEventns",
     menubar: false, 
     width: 800,
     height: 470,
     resize: false,
     fullpage: false,    
     selector: "textarea"
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.5.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<script>

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your trying to show the editor, but use the built in wp_editor function!

see here [wp_editor](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor)
&
here [tutsplus.com](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-wp_editor--wp-27136)

```
$settings = array(
   'wpautop' => false,       // auto add p tags to paragraphs
   'media_buttons' => false, // show or hide the media upload button
   'textarea_rows' => 10,    // how many rows you want in the text area
   'teeny' => false          // show or hide the compact editor view
);

$textAreaContent = 'get the data from database';
$editorID = 'id_of_the_editor';

wp_editor( $textAreaContent, $editorID, $settings );
```

this should produce a nice text editor like...

[image]

Comment: yea, I just picked the first google image I found!.. 
updated the image to something more what you should see!..

Comment: Thank you I will try with that

Comment: How to replace with this <textarea class="" name="conference_description"  ></textarea> to that  $textAreaContent = 'get the data from database';
$editorID = 'id_of_the_editor';

wp_editor( $textAreaContent, $editorID, $settings );

Comment: you dont have to write the textarea html, the options above will produce the textarea for you, the name can also be set by adding the option : textarea_name, by default it will use the ID you provide as the name.. you can also add the "editor_class" option to provide your own class name for the editor!..

Comment: $settings = array(
   'wpautop' => false,       // auto add p tags to paragraphs
   'media_buttons' => false, // show or hide the media upload button
   'textarea_rows' => 10,    // how many rows you want in the text area
   'teeny' => false          // show or hide the compact editor view
);

$textAreaContent = $_POST['abc'];
$editorID = 'id_of_the_editor';

wp_editor( $textAreaContent, $editorID, $settings );